# PyObjC giving strange error - [OC_PythonUnicode representations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x258ae2a0

Tags: python, objective-c, unicode, pyobjc

I have this line:

NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().setIcon_forFile_options_(unicode(icon),unicode(target),0)

Why does it give that error and how do I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread the documentation. I need to do this:

NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().setIcon_forFile_options_(NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(icon),target,0)

Unfortunately the error is what confused me.